# Save jsonb in postgres database

Tags: c#, postgresql, ef-core-6.0

I have a table in Postgres with a `jsonb` column. I'm using Entity Framework to upsert data on this table, but I'm always getting the error

> Input string was not in a correct format

because of the `jsonb` column.

This is an example of a query I generate:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (id, name, details) 
VALUES (1, 'john','{\r\n  \"age\": \"17\"\r\n}') 
ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
```

This is the command I'm trying to execute:

```
_context.ExecuteSqlRaw("INSERT INTO example_table (id, name, details) VALUES (1, 'john','{\r\n  \"age\": \"17\"\r\n}') ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING");
```

If I remove the `json` the query is executed perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json and Jsonb doesn't support `\n`, `\r` symbols. Use this:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (id, name, details) 
VALUES 
(1, 'john','{"age":"17"}') 
ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
```